# VueJS: How to retrieve url parameters after the page is redirected?

Tags: javascript, facebook, vue.js, amazon-cognito

I am using a Third Party Service to perform Login with Facebook (AWS Cognito), in my VueJS application.

I click on a button "Login with Facebook" which will invoke the third party url where a Sign Up with Facebook prompt will appear.

eg.

```js
window.location.href = https://my-cognito-app-domain/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=my_client_id&redirect_uri=my_redirect_url&identity_provider=Facebook
```

The user will input his/her Facebook credentials to authenticate.

Upon successful authentication, the user is redirect back to the VueJS application with *access_token* appended as a url parameter

eg. https://my-app-example.com/**#access_token=eyJraWQiOiIyRHViM0VrY2 ...**

I am trying to get the access_token in the context of my VueJS application do some logic on it. (Decode the jwt etc)

I have tried using window.location.search in *App.vue* when the application is *mounted* and *created*, but since the page is redirected I am unable to get this.

Below is the code sample:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">

  </div>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript">
  // @ is an alias to /src
import Navigation from '@/components/Navigation.vue'
import Footer from '@/components/Footer.vue'

export default {
  name: 'home',
  components: {
    Navigation,
    Footer
  },
  created(){
    console.log("created")
    var params = window.location.hash
    console.log(params)

  },
  mounted(){
      console.log("mounted")
      var params = window.location.hash
      console.log(params)
  }

}
```

I am expecting to get the access_token right after the page is redirected back to the VueJS application. I am I correct to say that App.vue is always reloaded after the page is redirected? If not is there way to track when the page is redirected?

Comment: You need `location.hash` instead; `location.search` contains the regular querystring starting with a `?`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window.location.search` contains `?` followed by the parameters of the URL.

Since the redirect link does not contain the `?` but `#`, you should use 
 `window.location.hash` instead, which contains `#` followed by the rest of the URL.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location#Properties

Comment: It seems that even console.log("created") and console.log("mounted") are never logged when the page is redirected, thank you for the suggestion